# Have a role to react discord.js

Tags: bots, discord

I am new to this of the Discord.js bots, what I want to do is that you need the "Kuro" role to react to the emoji. If you react and do not have it does nothing

This is the code:

```
message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 120000, errors: ['time'] })
.then(collected => {
    const reaction = collected.first();

    if (reaction.emoji.name === '❌') {
        message.edit("**A s d**");


    }
})
.catch(collected => {
    console.log(`After a minute, only ${collected.size} out of 4 reacted.`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd

Listen for `messageReactionAdd` (which gives you the [MessageReaction](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction) and the [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) that reacted)